# Efficiently inserting a variable number of rows into Postgres with a query that pg_stat_statements can aggregate

Tags: postgresql, pg-stat-statements

To reduce some of the query load on my database, I currently batch multiple queries together into one `INSERT` query with a variable number of rows. This produces queries like:

```
INSERT INTO example_table (column_1, column_2, ...)
VALUES ($1, $2, ...), ($3, $4, ...), ($5, $6, ...), ...
RETURNING "id";
```

Because the number of rows varies, from the perspective of the `pg_stat_statements` extension, it looks like lots of different types of queries are run.

I am looking to efficiently batch-insert several rows while allowing `pg_stat_statements` to aggregate all the query statistics together neatly. Is there some approach I can use to achieve this, perhaps by telling `pg_stat_statements` that these are all the same query type or by using prepared statements?

Comment: It is a potential improvement for `pg_stat_statements` not to differentiate by the length of lists. Why is it such a problem? You can aggregate the statistics for the variants in a `pg_stat_statements` query.

Comment: I'd prefer to see the aggregate stats and to streamline the entries in `pg_stat_statements`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I addressed this by inserting rows with [`UNNEST`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html), which allowed for a consistent query shape regardless of the number of rows inserted.

```
INSERT INTO example_table (column_1, column_2, ...)
  (SELECT * FROM UNNEST($1::uuid[], $2::varchar[], ...));
```

`UNNEST` worked because I didn't need to use `DEFAULT` in any of my rows. In some cases the array casts are not necessary, but I added them to be explicit. They are also needed for some types like `uuid[]`.

For my use case, the performance was comparable to that of `INSERT` queries with multiple `VALUE` tuples: `UNNEST` was faster on average but had a higher standard deviation across about 600k calls each.